# How to call a static class method with dynamically created arguments?

Tags: php, class, methods, static, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin dataTables to create an editable table on a website and I'm trying to make this call to the fields method accept arguments dynamically:

```
Editor::inst( $db, $table, $primary_key )
    ->fields(
        // this part needs to be dynamic
        Field::inst( 'value1' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' ),
        Field::inst( 'value2' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' )
    )
    ->process( $_POST )
    ->json();
```

I have value1 and value2 in an array, but there can be more than two. The number depends on the table I want to create:

```
$columns = array("value1", "value2");
```

How do I get them in the method call so that everything is evaluated correctly?

I really don't want to use *case*. There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the datatables documentation.

> The fields() method can take as many field instances as you wish to define and can also be called multiple times to add additional fields.

```php
$columns = array('value1', 'value2');
$editor = Editor::inst($db, $table, $primary_key);
foreach ($columns as $field) {
    $editor->fields(Field::inst($field)->validator('Validate::numeric'));
}
$editor->process($_POST)
    ->json();
```

You could also make the validator dynamic with something like:

```php
$columns = array('value1' => 'Validate::numeric', 'value2' => 'Validate::notEmpty');
$editor = Editor::inst($db, $table, $primary_key);
foreach ($columns as $field => $validator) {
    $editor->fields(Field::inst($field)->validator($validator));
}
$editor->process($_POST)
    ->json();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) and [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) functions to work with dynamic parameters.

You can use them like this,

```
function yourFunction() {
    $totalParams=func_num_args();    
    echo "Total parameters: ".$totalParams;
    $params = func_get_args();
    foreach($params as $i=>$param) {
         // $param is passed value.
         // $i is the index.
    }
}
```

Just call funtion like this,

```
yourFunction('param1value','param2value','param3value');
```

> **func_num_args()** returns the number of arguments passed to the function.
>   **func_get_args()** returns an array comprising a function's argument list.

Comment: Are you sure that is useful for my specific use case? I can't call the function like that, because I don't know how many arguments there will be.

Comment: As I've mentioned those two function doesn't rely on the method you call the function. It helps you to get all the arguments passed to a function without knowing the actual numbers.

Comment: Use func_get_args() inside your function use foreach to access all your parameters and use them to bind with query or anything else.

Comment: `func_get_args():  Called from the global scope - no function context` ...

Comment: May be this help you to solve http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php It has same error listed.

Comment: Nevermind. I'll repost this question and ask for a more detailled solution. Too many people just throwing function names at me with no good instructions on how to make use of them for my specific code. Your example is too general and doesn't relate to the question. Thanks anyway...